# optimize/improve Haskell code to list sub-sequence frequencies

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I wrote the code below to list sub-sequence frequencies of a list of lists (results include the sub-sequence and the indexes of the lists where the sub-sequence occurs). Does anyone have any suggestions how to make it more concise and/or efficient?

Sample output:

*Main> combFreq [[1,2,3,5,7,8],[2,3,5,6,7],[3,5,7,9],[1,2,3,7,9],[3,5,7,10]]
[([3,5],[0,1,2,4]),([2,3],[0,1,3]),([3,5,7],[0,2,4]),([5,7],[0,2,4]),([2,3,5],[0,1]),([1,2],[0,3]),([1,2,3],[0,3]),([7,9],[2,3])]

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function (on)

--[[1,2,3,5,7,8],[2,3,5,6,7],[3,5,7,9],[1,2,3,7,9],[3,5,7,10]]

tupleCat x y = (fst x, sort $ nub $ snd x ++ snd y)
isInResult x result = case lookup x result of
                        Just a  -> [a]
                        Nothing -> []

sInt xs = concat $ sInt' (csubs xs) 0 (length xs) where
    csubs = map (filter (not . null) . concatMap inits . tails)
    sInt' []     _     _       = []
    sInt' (x:xs) count origLen = 
        let result = (zip (zip (replicate (length xs) count) [count+1..origLen]) 
                 $ map (\y -> intersect x y) xs)
        in concatMap (\x -> let a = fst x in map (\y -> (y,a)) (snd x))
                 result : sInt' xs (count + 1) origLen

concatResults [] result     = result 
concatResults (x:xs) result = 
    let match = isInResult (fst x) result 
        newX  = (fst x, [fst $ snd x, snd $ snd x])
    in  if not (null match)
        then let match'    = (fst x, head match)
                 newResult = deleteBy (\x -> (==match')) match' result
             in concatResults xs (tupleCat match' newX : newResult)
        else concatResults xs (newX : result)

combFreq xs =
  filter (\x -> length (fst x) > 1)
  $ reverse $ sortBy (compare `on` (length . snd)) $ concatResults (sInt xs) []
```

Comment: ([3,5,7],[0,2,4]), what does it mean ?

Comment: @zurgl If I understand it properly, it means that the subsequence `[3,5,7]` appears in the lists at indices `[0, 2, 4]`.

Comment: Have you tried using optimization (`-O2`), using llvm (`-fllvm`), profiling for hot spots, determining mutator vs GC time (`-sstderr`), benchmarking variations using criterion, using unboxed vectors instead of lists, or using stream fusion (`import Data.List.Stream`)?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I have yet to learn about all of those things ... thank you for the learning direction

Comment: Note: `sort $ nub $ snd x ++ snd y` does things in the wrong order. `map head . group . sort $ snd x ++ snd y` is much more efficient, unless you have a lot of often repeated elements. But in your case, I think you're doing it only with lists where both lists have only unique elements, so sorting first is much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would go about doing it. I haven't compared it for performance,
and it is certainly naive. It enumerates all the contiguous subsequences for
each list and gathers them into a `Map`. It should meet your requirement of
more concise though.

```
import Data.List as L
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as M

nonEmptySubs :: [a] -> [[a]]
nonEmptySubs = filter (not . null)
             . concatMap tails
             . inits

makePairs :: (a -> [a]) -> [a] -> [(a, Int)]
makePairs f xs = concat $ zipWith app xs [0 .. ]
    where app y i = zip (f y) (repeat i)

results :: (Ord a) => [[a]] -> Map [a] [Int]
results =
    let ins acc (seq, ind) = M.insertWith (++) seq [ind] acc
        -- Insert the index at the given sequence as a singleton list
    in foldl' ins M.empty . makePairs nonEmptySubs

combFreq :: (Ord a) => [[a]] -> [([a], [Int])]
combFreq = filter (not . null . drop 1 . snd) -- Keep subseqs with more than 1 match
         . filter (not . null . drop 1 . fst) -- keep subseqs longer than 1
         . M.toList
         . results
```

Just note that this version will give the same qualitative results, but it will
not have the same ordering.

My biggest recommendation is to break things down more and leverage what you
can from some of the standard libraries to do the tedious work. Notice that we
can break a lot of the work down into separate stages and then compose those
stages to get the final function.

Comment: I'm quite sure that it will also be considerably faster on input of not too small size. One point, though, don't use `((> 1) . length)`, that is bad if the length is large, use `not . null . drop 1`. Possibly one might need a stricter insert function, but if `M.insertWith (++)` isn't good enough, you'd probably need a custom type for the index lists anyway.

Comment: @DanielFischer Good point on `length`. It may be better to prefer `HashMap` over `Map` if the sequence elements have an expensive comparison function, since many of the subsequences will share long prefixes.

Comment: Right, `HashMap` may be better, or perhaps a trie.

Answer (score 0):

If all your lists are increasing (like they are in your example) the following should work (not a beauty as I'm a Haskell-newbie; comments about how to improve are very welcome):

```
import Control.Arrow (first, second)

compFreq ls = cF [] [] ls
  where cF rs cs ls | all null ls = rs
                    | otherwise   = cF (rs++rs') (cs'' ++ c ++ cs') ls'
          where m = minimum $ map head $ filter (not . null) ls
                ls' = map (\l -> if null l || m < head l then l
                                                         else tail l) ls
                is = map snd $ filter ((==m) . head . fst) $ filter (not . null . fst) $ zip ls [0,1..]
                c = if atLeastTwo is then [([m], is)] else []
                fs = filter (\(vs, is') -> atLeastTwo $ combine is is') cs
                cs' = map (\(vs, is') -> (vs++[m], combine is is')) fs
                cs'' = map (second (filter (not . (`elem` is)))) cs
                rs' = filter ok cs'
                combine _ [] = []
                combine [] _ = []
                combine (i:is) (i':is') | i<i' = combine is (i':is')
                                        | i>i' = combine (i:is) is'
                                        | i==i' = i:combine is is'
                atLeastTwo = not . null . drop 1
                ok (js, ts) = atLeastTwo js && atLeastTwo ts
```

The idea is to process the lists by looking always at the minimal value m, which is removed from all lists to get ls'. The list of indices is tells where m was removed. The inner working function cF has two extra parameters: the list rs of results up to now and the list cs of current subsequences. The minimal value starts a new subsequence c if it occurs at least twice. cs' are subsequences which end with m and cs'' are those without m. The new results rs' all contain m as last element.

The output for your example is

```
[([1,2],[0,3]),([2,3],[0,1,3]),([1,2,3],[0,3]),([3,5],[0,1,2,4]),([2,3,5],[0,1]),([5,7],[0,2,4]),([3,5,7],[0,2,4]),([7,9],[2,3])]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It might take me a while to get my head around it.